# Symbols get thrown around in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I wanted to ask this question for a long time. When I echo for example a box using hashtags, and put inside some text, this happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VnZq.png

And without the text, it looks normal:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyOw7.png

So I made a moving system in batch, and when I opened it it ended up looking like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUxf4.png

Here's the code, thank you very much if you find an answer and a fix for this.

```
@echo off
@title batch rpg
cls
color 0f
:initsetup
set xc=3
set yc=3
:displaysetup
cls
set X1Y1=  
set X1Y2=  
set X1Y3= 
set X1Y4=    
set X2Y1=  
set X2Y2=
set X2Y3=  
set X2Y4=    
set X3Y1=  
set X3Y2=  
set X3Y3=  
set X3Y4=   
set X4Y1=  
set X4Y2= 
set X4Y3= 
set X4Y4=   
:SCREEN
set X%xc%Y%yc%=@
echo  ....
echo .%X1Y4%%X2Y4%%X3Y4%%X4Y4%.
echo .%X1Y3%%X2Y3%%X3Y3%%X4Y3%.
echo .%X1Y2%%X2Y2%%X3Y2%%X4Y2%.
echo .%X1Y1%%X2Y1%%X3Y1%%X4Y1%.
echo  ....
choice /c wasd /n 
set choice=%ERRORLEVEL%
goto choice%choice%

:choice1
set /A yc=%yc%+1
if %yc% GTR 4 (
    set /A yc=%yc%-1
    goto displaysetup
) ELSE (
    goto displaysetup
)

:choice2
set /A xc=%xc%-1
if %xc% LSS 1 (
    set /A xc=%xc%+1
    goto displaysetup
) ELSE (
    goto displaysetup
)

:choice3
set /A yc=%yc%-1
if %yc% LSS 1 (
    set /A yc=%yc%+1
    goto displaysetup
) ELSE (
    goto displaysetup
)

:choice4
set /A xc=%xc%+1
if %xc% GTR 4 (
    set /A xc=%xc%-1
    goto displaysetup
) ELSE (
    goto displaysetup
)
```

Comment: X1Y4= 4 spaces. X2Y4= 4 spaces. X3Y4= 3 spaces X4Y4= 3 spaces. What were you expecting it to do?  It is displaying exactly like you have it programmed.

Comment: If you want to **GUARANTEE** that each XY coordinate is equal to one space then use quotes as a best practice. `set "X1Y1= "`.  Just get into the habit of always using quotes for the assignment of a variable.

Comment: Hey Squashman, thanks for your help, it worked. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: I would suggest you use a text editor like Notepad++ where it will display all the white space characters for you. That way you can troubleshoot problems like this yourself.